# How do the "max" and "min" blocks in the MIT App Inventor work?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am trying to create an app in the MIT App Inventor that is able to discover the smallest and largest number within a set given by the user.

I saw that the App Inventor has blocks that do just this, aptly called "max" and "min", but I cannot figure out how to use them. They find the "largest" and "smallest" in a set of numbers, but what could I actually connect to these blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see also the [reference docu](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/math-blocks.html#min)

```
min
Returns the smallest of a given set of numbers.

max
Returns the largest of a given set of numbers.
```

example

[image]

see also the [Colored Dots tutorial](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/colored-dots.html) and the **limit range** procedure for a more complex example

Comment: This explains these blocks extremely well. Thank you so much! :)